# Knee going a completely different direction from the pole

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

As the tittle says, i'm still trying to figure out rigging, but no matter what i try, when i think i finished working with the legs, the knee bends unnaturally when i'm imitating a crouching motion

[image: The knee, supposed to move towards the pole in front of it, moves to the left instead]

And that's only sometimes, the other times the knee moves completely away from the pole, like it's repelled or something

This is my IK setup ("Talón" means heel, the target, and "rodilla" means knee, the pole), i recalculated the roles and everything all the tutorials i checked said i have to do

[image: My IK setup, showing a pole angle of 90° of rotation, 500 iterations and a chain lenght of two]

Comment: bend the knee in edit mode a bit in direction of the pole so Blender "knows" the direction

Comment: If Chris' answer doesn't work please share your file

Comment: You’ve got the IK limits set up on the knee and such, right?

Comment: If by that you mean the chain lenght, yes, i did

Comment: Your character looks in the direction of the X-axis. That means it looks to the left or right. You have cut the screenshot so I can't tell exactly. Press the *Numpad_1* key for the front view. Rotate your character (mesh and armature) so it looks to you. Apply the *Rotation* to the mesh and the armature (Ctrl+A). Then try another value for the *Pole Angle* like 180, 0, or -90. (the value depends on how you've aligned the bones in *Edit* mode.)